# How to connect to monetdb with perl

Tags: perl, monetdb

I am trying to connect to monetdb with perl code, it hangs. I am not able to connect nor it is throwing an error to get it resolved.
Please find the below code ,

```
`#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI();
use POSIX;
print "\nStart a simple Monet MIL interaction\n\n";
print "MonetDB\n";
my $host = 'XYZ.com';
my $port = '123';
my $user = 'test';
my $password = 'test';
my @ds = DBI->data_sources('monetdb');
print "Data sources: @ds\n";
my $dsn = "dbi:monetdb:host=$host;port=$port;database=testdb";
my $dbh = DBI->connect( $dsn,$user, $password, { PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1 });
```

`

Please help me with it.

Comment: Is it the actual call to `connect()` that is hanging? I see that [DBD::monetdb](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::monetdb) hasn't been updated for twelve years so, to be honest, I'm not sure I'd really trust it to work. Might be work contacting the author.

Comment: Thanks for the response

Comment: Thanks for the response